# Android Notification, do stuff on click

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I've read documentation. But i found only a way to call my activity on click with Intent

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyMain.class), 0);
```

But how do i make some action, e.g switching view in wievflipper and only then opening activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add extras to your Intent, and then retrieve those in your activity.

See the [putExtra(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Also, refer to the [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) for a full working code.

Comment: i can not find a way to do viewflipper.SetDisaplyedCHild(int) with putExtra()